# Манипуляции со словарями, Python

Tags: python, словари

Написал вот такой код:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import datetime


slovar = [{'date': datetime.date(2022, 8, 20), 'type': 'WRITE'},
          {'date': datetime.date(2022, 8, 18), 'type': 'READ'},
          {'date': datetime.date(2022, 8, 18), 'type': 'WRITE'}]

historic = defaultdict(list)

for i in slovar:
    date, type = i['date'], i['type']
    historic[date].append(type)

print(dict(historic))
>>>{datetime.date(2022, 8, 20): ['WRITE'], datetime.date(2022, 8, 18): ['READ', 'WRITE']}
```

Не могу сообразить, как привести его к такому вот виду(т.е., чтобы словари были внутри словаря + сортировка по дате + подсчет READ и WRITE и привязка их к дате):

```
>>>{{datetime.date(2022, 8, 18): {'READ': 1, 'WRITE': 1}, datetime.date(2022, 8, 20): {'WRITE': 1}}
```

Помогите, пожалуйста

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Сортировка

Сортировать словарь я бы не стал. Вы всегда можете его обойти без предварительной сортировки в нужном порядке:

```
# обработка ключей в хронологическом порядке
for k in sorted(historic.keys()):
    pass
```

Или:

```
# обработка ключей и значений в хронологическом порядке
for k, v in sorted(historic.items()):
    pass
```

Но если вам всё-таки нужен именно сортированный словарь, то добавьте к любому рецепту ниже немного сортировки:

```
historic = dict(sorted(historic.items()))
```

### Построение словаря

[collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import defaultdict, Counter


historic = defaultdict(Counter)
for i in slovar:
    historic[i['date']][i['type']] += 1
```

> ```
> defaultdict(<class 'collections.Counter'>,
>             {datetime.date(2022, 8, 18): Counter({'READ': 1, 'WRITE': 1}),
>              datetime.date(2022, 8, 20): Counter({'WRITE': 1})})
> ```

Если хочется обойтись без `Counter`, вариант с обычными словарями:

```
from collections import defaultdict


historic = defaultdict(dict)
for i in slovar:
    type_ = i['type']
    d = historic[i['date']]
    d.setdefault(type_, 0)
    d[type_] += 1
```

> ```
> defaultdict(<class 'dict'>,
>             {datetime.date(2022, 8, 18): {'READ': 1, 'WRITE': 1},
>              datetime.date(2022, 8, 20): {'WRITE': 1}})
> ```

И вариант полностью на обычных словарях:

```
historic = {}
for i in slovar:
    type_ = i['type']
    d = historic.setdefault(i['date'], {})
    d.setdefault(type_, 0)
    d[type_] += 1
```

> ```
> {datetime.date(2022, 8, 18): {'READ': 1, 'WRITE': 1},
>  datetime.date(2022, 8, 20): {'WRITE': 1}}
> ```

Comment: Огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import defaultdict, Counter
import datetime


slovar = [{'date': datetime.date(2022, 8, 20), 'type': 'WRITE'},
          {'date': datetime.date(2022, 8, 18), 'type': 'READ'},
          {'date': datetime.date(2022, 8, 18), 'type': 'WRITE'}]

historic = defaultdict(Counter)

for i in slovar:
    date, type_ = i.values()
    historic[date][type_] += 1

historic_sort = {d: dict(historic[d]) for d in sorted(historic.keys())}
print(historic_sort)
```

Но вообще не дело полагаться на порядок следования ключей в словаре.

Comment: Извините, но пишет, что "date, type_ = i.values()
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)"

Comment: @DaniilDemchenko Значит в вашем реальном словаре полей больше. Тогда делайте как раньше `i['date'], i['type']`

Comment: понял, спасибо!